# How to save the values of a dynamic variable constantly?

Tags: dynamic

Suppose I have:

```
x = Dynamic[MousePosition[]]
```

How can I save all the values of x when I move the mouse?

Using the code below add the positions even if the mouse stays at the same place. It would be nice to have control over when to start and finish the saving of values:

```
data = {};
Dynamic[AppendTo[data,MousePosition[]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you might do this based on an example in the docs for `MoustPosition[]` under 'Properties and Relations':

```
exportedList = {};
DynamicModule[
 {list = {{0.0, 0.0}}, y = Null,acq=False},
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[
   If[acq&&(y!=Last@list), y = MousePosition["Graphics"];AppendTo[list, y]];
   Framed@
    Graphics[{Red, Line[list], Point[list]}, PlotLabel -> {y, acq}, 
     PlotRange -> 2]
   ]
  , {"MouseClicked" :> (acq = Not[acq];If[acq,list={0.0,0.0};exportedList=list])}
  ]
 ]
```

To control acquisition you use an EventHandler with "MouseClicked" as the trigger, this toggles the `acq` variable between true/false, reinitializes `list` when you start a new acquisition, and exports the list to an external variable when acquisition ends. Dynamic only appends to list when `acq` is `True` and the current position of the mouse is not equal to the last stored position.

I will say I'm not sure about the timing of dynamic, so I can't say when this updates. But depending on what you're doing it might be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `TrackedSymbols` keeps the system from updating every time `data` is changed:

```
data = {};
Dynamic[AppendTo[data, MousePosition[]], TrackedSymbols :> {}]
```

Knowing the actual use-case might lead to better recommendations.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to draw over the boundaries of an object in an image and using the saved coordinates later I extract that object from the image. In summary, I want to make a region of interest by mouse or pen and then use the resulting region of interest to get image properties related to the region of interest.